# Checkbox in each row in the table to get values and insert in database

Tags: php, checkbox, pdo

I'm working with send mail function of my page. To be able to get the values in the table I want to add a checkbox in each row that can tick more than 1 rows. Then once submitted by a button, it will be inserted in the database. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Please help.

Here's the checkbox:

```
 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkb[".$row['ID']."]'></td>";
```

Here's the code:

```
 function InsertEmailMessage() {

 foreach ($_POST['checkb'] as $id => $val) {

 if($val=='checked'){
 $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE ID='".$id."'";
 $conn = dbConnect();
 $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql6); 
 $stmt6->execute();
 $data = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
 $conn=null;
 }

 foreach ($data as $row6) {

 $invnumb=$row6['Invoice_Number'];
 $partnumb=$row6['Part_Number'];
 $issue=$row6['Issues'];
 $pic=$row6['PIC_Comments'];
 $emailadd= $row6['PersoninCharge'];
 $issuetype=$row6['Issue_Type'];
 $createdate=$row6['Creation_Date'];
 $site=$row6['Site'];
 $vendor=$row6['Vendor_Name'];
 $invdate=$row6['Invoice_Date'];
 $po=$row6['PO'];
 $rr=$row6['RR']; 
 $currency=$row6['Currency'];
 $invamount=$row6['Invoice_Amount'];
 $stat=$row6['Status'];


 if($row6['Status']=="Open") {

 $message = "<html><b>Issue Type: {$issuetype} </b><br><br>";       
 $message .= "<b>Creation Date: {$createdate} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Site: {$site} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Vendor Name: {$vendor} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Invoice Date: {$invdate} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Invoice Number: {$invnumb} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Part Number:</b><br>{$partnumb}<br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>PO: {$po} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>RR: {$rr} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Currency: {$currency} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Invoice Amount: {$invamount} </b><br><br>";
 $message .= "<b>Issues:</b><br>{$issue}<br>";
 $message .= "<b>Status: {$stat} </b><br><br>";  
 $message .= "<b>{$pic}<b><br>";  
 $message .= "</html>";


 if(!empty($emailadd)) {
 dbInsertEmailMessage($emailadd, "Invoice Number: {$invnumb} - {$issue}.", $message);
 echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent to {$emailadd}')</script>";
 }
 }
 }

 }
 }
 }

 function dbInsertEmailMessage($send_to, $subject, $message) {

  $sql7 = "INSERT INTO email_queue (send_to, subject, message) VALUES (:send_to, :subject, :message)";  
  $conn = dbConnect();
  $stmt7 = $conn->prepare($sql7); 
  $stmt7->bindParam(':send_to', $send_to);
  $stmt7->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
  $stmt7->bindParam(':message', $message);
  $stmt7->execute();
  $conn=null; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems wrong:

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkb[".$row['ID']."]'></td>
```

If you are in PHP, echo example:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkb[\'' . $row['ID'] . '\']"></td>';
```

If you are in HTML:

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkb["<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"]'></td>
```

Then in your sending function you could try some debugging with:

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

Comment: I'm using php. Where exactly should i put the var_dump( $_POST );

Comment: Just after the line `function InsertEmailMessage() {` you could put: `var_dump( $_POST ); return;` - in this way you can check if the checkboxes names and values are exactly like you expect.

Comment: Try to look the source code of the page, perhaps the var_dump is hidden by something else

Answer (score 0):

This way of declaring is wrong.

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkb[".$row['ID']."]'></td>";
```

Change this to

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkb[]' value='".$row['ID']."'></td>";
```

Way of getting selected checkbox is

```
$checkb=$_POST['checkb'];

$TotalCheckbox=$sizeof($checkb);
for($i=0;$i<$TotalCheckbox;$i++)
{
    echo $Selcheckb=$checkb[$i];
}
```

Now, Do whatever you want with this `$Selcheckb`..

```
.
.
.
// Your code.
```

It Should Be like this.

```
<?
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkb[]' value='".$row['ID']."'></td>";

function InsertEmailMessage() 
{
        $checkb=$_POST['checkb'];
        $TotalCheckbox=$sizeof($checkb);
        for($i=0;$i<$TotalCheckbox;$i++)
        {
             $Selcheckb=$checkb[$i];
             $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE ID=$Selcheckb";
             $conn = dbConnect();
             $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql6); 
             $stmt6->execute();
             $data = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
             $conn=null;
        }
.
.// Your rest of the code..
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I use $Selcheckb? Where should I inserted it?

Comment: @KimlynTormes : I updated my answer. Please go through it. Since, your checkbox declaration was wrong. I made it correct. And, First function will work accordingly. Since, i don't know about your database tables/column so, i can't edit your full code. But, Checkbox code i've updated. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: @KimlynTormes : Please let me know about your work progress.

Comment: still not inserting row in the database.

Comment: @KimlynTormes : you removed `foreach ($_POST['checkb'] as $id => $val) { // }` with my code ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95028/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-kimlyn-tormes).